# Why Gulp does not keep file names returned from dest function?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the following file paths:

```
resources/assets/css/site1/app.css
resources/assets/css/site2/app.css
resources/assets/css/common/common.css
```

and I would like them to be copied to `public` folder without keeping my nested folder structure. Obviously, I need to modify target file names because I have two `app.css` here. So, I decided to take the last folder of the path as a prefix for filename (and also add `-dev` postfix because these files are only for development mode and will be deleted when building final release with elixir minification). As the result I should get:

```
public/css/site1-app-dev.css
public/css/site2-app-dev.css
public/css/common-common-dev.css
```

Now I have the following gulp code:

```
gulp.src("resources/assets/css/**/*.css")
    .pipe(gulp.dest(
    function(file) { 
        var newPath = "public/css/" + 
           // folder name, like admin or public
           path.basename(path.dirname(file.path)) + "-" +
           path.basename(file.path, ".css") + "-dev.css";

        console.log(newPath);

        return newPath;
    }));
```

I see that console outputs the result as expected. But at the end I get the following files:

```
public/css/site1-app-dev.css/site1/app.css
public/css/site2-app-dev.css/site2/app.css
public/css/common-common-dev.css/common/common.css
```

Obviously, gulp treats `newPath` as a folder name to use when copying the files matching `**/*.css` and preserving the folder hierarchy.

**Is there any way to tell gulp that I actually want it to treat `newPath` as the final destination filename and not as a directory?**

Comment: `gulp.dest` can only alter `directory`, if you want to change `file name`, better check `gulp-rename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gulp-rename` to add suffix on file names, the `base` is specified to keep the nested folder structure.

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.src("resources/assets/css/**/*.css", {base: 'resources/assets/css/'})
   .pipe(rename({ suffix: "-dev", }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest("public/css/"));
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename